# When app in background state i want Cancel or remove remote notification from notification bar in react native push notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When my react native app is in background or kill state I want to create one modify local notification from remote notification.so i have 2 notification created.
so i want to remove or delete remote notification from notification bar.[Screenshots of as of now giving notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF496.jpg)

I want to delete or remove remote notification app in background state and kill state. and create local notification refer title and body of remote notification.[I want to delete one remote notification from notification bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knPJx.jpg)

Comment: You can use `AppState` from `react-native` to listen for app focus changes and accordingly perform a task. The library you are using to display the notification must have a `removeNotification` function. You can use that function when the app goes in background state.